# How can I get the Flutter "camera" package example to recognise cameras when embedded in a project?

Tags: flutter, android-camera

I have been trying to use the example from the flutter "camera" package:
https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/camera/camera/example/lib/main.dart.
This works perfectly as a stand-alone project (copied and pasted into "main.dart"), but refuses to recognise my cameras when I rename and save it as "camera.dart" in another project.
The relevant code seems to be (lines 1045-1069):

```
/// CameraApp is the Main Application.
class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Default Constructor
  const CameraApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: CameraExampleHome(),
    );
  }
}

List<CameraDescription> _cameras = <CameraDescription>[];

Future<void> main() async {
  // Fetch the available cameras before initializing the app.
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    _cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    _logError(e.code, e.description);
  }
  runApp(const CameraApp());
}
```

The test is (lines 576-580):

```
    if (_cameras.isEmpty) {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        showInSnackBar('No camera found.');
      });
      return const Text('None');
```

Any suggestions on what should be added, changed, altered? probably something mind-numbingly obvious that I'm just overlooking...